# how to create a variable radius in map view

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have a map view and I want to add a variable radius like in the find friends app, allowing the user to drag to make the radius smaller or bigger. How do I do this? Is there any prebuilt functionality that allows you to do this easily?

[image: find friends snap shot]

Answer (score 0):

[`MKCircle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKCircle_class/Reference/Reference.html) is the class you are looking for. It conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol, so you can just use it like any other annotation. Use the [`MKCircleView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKCircleView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKCircleView) class for the actual drawing of the circle (also check the available sample code).

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible by just using a custom MKAnnotationView that shows a circle? That will maintain size as you zoom around.